# ValueMember doesn't "extract" from Data Source

Tags: c#, readfile

I tried to extract comboBox `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` from a file, using this code:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dbfile).Select(d => new
{
    Display = d.Split(':').First(),
    Value = Convert.ToInt32(d.Split(':').Last().Replace(";", ""))
}).ToList();
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

While the file "dbfile" looks like this:

```
DIRT:3;
STONE:6;
```

It adds the items DIRT and STONE into the comboBox, but when I try to get the value member, for example with

```
label2.Text = comboBox1.ValueMember;
```

The Text of label2 will be "ValueMember" and not "3".
Whats the problem, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get the selected value, not the value member. There is a special property for that, `SelectedValue`:

```
label2.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought the SelectedValue property would output the display and not the value.